# Не могу изменить ширину элемента с помощью "width"

Tags: css

Есть div, которому нужно изменить ширину.

```
<div id="inhere">
     <input type="text" name="message_input">       
</div>
```

css:

```
#inhere{
    margin-left: 450px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Однако необходимого результата это не дает. Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: В показанном коде изменение ширины div'а визуально ничего не изменит, потому что сам инпут имеет изначально маленькую ширину. Вы точно не хотите менять ширину инпута?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу изменить размер input`а?

Comment: #inhere input {
    width: 500px;
}

Comment: Спасибо большое!